# podeis revisar mi alarma android?

Tags: java, android

Estoy intentando implementar una alarma en Android con un intent, pero me sale un error sobre resolvedActivity. En principio si quito el bucle abre la alarma pero no graba la hora que vengo programando. Me sucede lo mismo con Dial al establecer la llamada a un teléfono a través de un botón. Necesito ayuda

public void crearAlarma(View view) {

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(AlarmClock.ACTION_SET_ALARM)

            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MESSAGE, "Ir al trabajo")
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_HOUR, 22)
            .putExtra(AlarmClock.EXTRA_MINUTES, 15);

    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);


    }
}
```